# Drill to Hive connectivity error(org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed))

Tags: java, apache, azure, hadoop, hive

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR hive.log - Got exception: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) while trying to connect Drill to Hive.
```

For "Hive" Microsoft Azure HDInsight(Ranger Enabled) (Remote metastore (MS SQL Server)) is getting used and for Drill I am using other VM which is under same VNet as cluster. 
I am able to make Drill Storage plugin with below configuration

```
{
"type": "hive",
"enabled": true,
"configProps": {
"hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://hn0-xyz.cloudapp.net:9083,thrift://hn1-    xyz.cloudapp.net:9083",
"hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/hive/warehouse",
"fs.default.name": "wasb://qwerty@demo.blob.core.windows.net",
"hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
}
}
```

Stack Trace of error:

```
17:57:19.515 [2779bbff-d7a9-058c-d133-b41795a0ee58:foreman] ERROR hive.log - Got exception: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.flush(TIOStreamTransport.java:161) ~[drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:65) ~[drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.send_get_all_databases(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:733) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_all_databases(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:726) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getAllDatabases(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1031) ~[hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at org.apache.drill.exec.store.hive.DrillHiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabasesHelper(DrillHiveMetaStoreClient.java:205) [drill-storage-hive-core-1.9.0.jar:1.9.0]
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>fs.azure.account.keyprovider.kkhdistore.blob.core.windows.net</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.ShellDecryptionKeyProvider</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.azure.shellkeyprovider.script</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/hdinsight_common/decrypt.sh</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.azure.account.key.kkhdistore.blob.core.windows.net</name>
    <value>{COPY FROM CLUSTER core-site.xml}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb</value>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the section [`Non-public ports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-port-settings-for-services#non-public-ports) of the offical docuement `Ports and URIs used by HDInsight`, as the note below said, I doubt the Hive you used was installed manually on Azure HDInsight cluster, not Hive cluster type.

> Some services are only available on specific cluster types. For example, HBase is only available on HBase cluster types.

So the thrift port `9083` is non-public port for others like Drill even if they are under the same VNet. The solution for the issue is that following the document [`Extend HDInsight capabilities by using Azure Virtual Network`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network) to create a rule to allow the inbound of the port at the NSG of the cluster. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. In HDInsight there is no option to create inbound and outbound rules.